# Prove that the Euclidean distance $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$ is negative definite

Tags: functional-analysis, positive-definite, optimal-transport

In the book Computational Optimal Transport, the authors give the following definition for positive and negative definite functions:

**Def 1.** A symmetric function $k$ defined on a set $\mathcal X \times \mathcal X$ is said positive definite if for any $n \geq 0$, the familiy $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathcal X$ and vector $r \in \mathbb R^n$ the following inequality holds:
$$
\sum^n_{i,j = 1} r_i r_j k(x_i,x_j) \geq 0
$$
The negative definite is just the opposite inequality. Finally, we call $k$ conditionally positive if this inequality if valid only for $r$ such that $\sum_i r_i = 0$.

Then the authors claim that the Euclidean distance is negative definite. My question is, how does one prove that indeed it is negative definite? I can perhaps prove that it is conditionally negative, but I don't see how to prove the actual claim.

Comment: What happens if $r_i$ are all positive?

Comment: Exactly. That’s why I don’t see how this could be true. Only conditionally

Comment: Perhaps he meant conditionally. I’ll try to write the author.

Comment: The definition of negative definite specifies that $\sum_{i}r_i = 0$, and that $\sum_{i,j}r_ir_jk(x_i,x_j) \leq 0$ under that condition.

Comment: If you let $k(x,y)=d^2(x,y)$, then it is well-known that $k$ is conditionally negative definite. (This is a result of I.J.Schoenberg from the late 1930s; see https://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/Schoenberg3.pdf for this & much more.)